# Button in Material UI is transparent when loading

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, tailwind-css

Every time I start a new project with Material UI, I have the same problem with buttons ignoring their primary color. For a second when loading, the background color is clearly visible, but after that the button is transparent.

I have installed all the necessary packages:

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

And just placed a button like this:

```
import {Button} from "@mui/material";
<Button variant="contained" color="primary">Contained</Button>
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
I found that if I delete the following line from globals.css, the Material UI works as it should. But I need this because we will also use tailwind for styling

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must [disable preflight](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#disabling-preflight) in your TailwindCSS configuration to prevent defaults overriding MUI styling:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  }
}
```

If you have not done so already, you should also follow [MUI instructions for changing the CSS injection order](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#css-injection-order-2) if you are going to use external style sheets in order to reliably style MUI components using TailwindCSS.